# How to change Class on span in Code Behind

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar hyperlink button where I want to change the Font Awesome icon shown in the span in the Code behind.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right" id="sub_navbar1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="hypMemo" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#">
        <span class="fa fa-sticky-note-o" runat="server" id="imgMemo"></span>
        <span class="">&nbsp;Memo</span>
      </asp:HyperLink>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to change the class on the span `imgMemo` to `fa fa-sticky-note` in the code behind.  Basically, I use logic based on whether a memo is attached to the record to show one icon or another.

I've tried to look at setting the attribute on this span in the code behind but can't find how to make it work.

Comment: You would like some javascript to find the element with id "imgMemo" and change the class of the element if the next span element has the details "&nbsp;Mem"?

Comment: Actually the way I got around it was to add to span with id on them and the font awesome image I wanted and in the code behind, I would make one visible and the other not.